# Setting Date format yyyyMMdd through specify Culture Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, format, culture

I want to set user date format yyyyMMdd using culture name. Which culture name have to specify to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use the format specifier?

```
string s = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

I'm not aware of any pre-rolled cultures that use this specifier. You could perhaps roll your own culture?

Comment: If I set the culture name, don't need to handle MaskedEditExtender and CalendarExtender and no other handling required

Comment: @Muhammad: by setting the culture you will also affect other things, such as numeric formats (thousand separator, decimal character), currency symbols and such.

Comment: the issue here is , MaskedEditExtender only validate when we set culture property, rather only set date format.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own culture using the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class (in assembly *sysglobl*). But it may be overkill for your need...

Another, simpler solution : create a new instance of CultureInfo based on the current culture, and assign it a custom DateTimeFormatInfo :

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dtfi.ShortDateTimePattern = "yyyyMMdd";
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.DateTimeFormat = dtfi;
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27053/Culture-Specific-Number-Formatting-in-ASP-NET) might help you in understanding number and DateTime formatting as well as culture specific formatting overriding. It basically demonstrates it by remodifying the [msdn code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx):